# Perfect matching in a graph and complete matching in bipartite graph

Tags: graphs, matching, bipartite-matching

When I [google for complete matching](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=complete%20matching), first link points to [perfect matching on wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerfectMatching.html).

It defines perfect matching as follows:

> A perfect matching of a graph is a matching (i.e., an independent edge set) in which every vertex of the graph is incident to exactly one edge of the matching.  A perfect matching is therefore a matching containing $n/2$ edges (the largest possible), meaning perfect matchings are only possible on graphs with an even number of vertices.

However below graph contains even number of vertices (10 vertices), but still I cant guess the perfect matching - ***in which every vertex of of the graph is incident to exactly one edge***. One of the matching can be $\{E_1,E_4,E_6\}$. However not every vertex (here, $\{V_5,V_6,V_9,V_{10}\}$) is incident to exactly one edge in this matching as required by above definition. So this is not definitely a perfect matching as desired by wolfram's definition. Also I cannot add any other edge to this matching as it will make two edges to share a vertex.

**Q1.** Is perfect matching possible with this graph?

[image]

I am also reading the same topic from the [book by Narsingh Deo](http://www.amazon.in/Theory-Applications-Engineering-Computer-Science/dp/8120301455). It defines the complete matching in the context of bipartite graph:

> In a bipartite graph having a vertex partition $V_1$ and $V_2$ a **complete matching of vertices in set $V_1$ into those in $V_2$** is a matching in which there is one edge incident with every vertex in $V_1$. In other words, every vertex in $V_1$ is matched against some vertex in $V_2$.

I am not able to understand if these two (wolfram's and book's) definitions point to two different concepts or they are one and same.

By my understanding, according to Deo's definition, $V_2$ may contain more vertices than that in $V_1$, thus the size matching may be less than $n/2$. However, wolfram says perfect matching contains $n/2$ edges. For example in above graph the **complete matching of vertices in set $P_1$ into those in $P_2$** can be $\{E_1,E_4,E_6\}$ as one edge in this matching is incident with every vertex in $P_1$.

**Q2.** So the two definitions (wolfram's and book's) must be different concepts. Am I correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are two different concepts. A *perfect matching* is a matching involving all the vertices. A *bipartite perfect matching* (especially in the context of [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall%27s_marriage_theorem)) is a matching in a bipartite graph which involves completely one of the bipartitions. If the bipartite graph is balanced – both bipartitions have the same number of vertices – then the concepts coincide.

The term *bipartite perfect matching* is not standard – in fact I just made it up. Usually *perfect matching* just means a matching involving all the vertices.

Comment: +1 for the term "*bipartite perfect matching*", serves the purpose of distinguishing the two concepts and also gives identity to the this particular concept, though is simple one

Comment: Just as an addendum to a sufficient answer, the comparitively more frequent term for the aforementioned 'bipartite perfect matching' is 'X-saturating matching'.

Answer (score 1):

Yuval is right. A perfect matching in a bipartite graph, may be restricted and defined differently as a matching, which covers only one part of the graph. Note that according to such a definition, the number of vertices in the graph may be odd. For example, you can delete say $V_{10}$ of your example, and your matching is still perfect in the restricted sense.